# How to control many videos with a single code block

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, video, embed

I have a problem. I have 2 videos in 1 page. My code is like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="thumbnail-img">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <video id="video2">
                    <source src="video/inspiration-1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary play" onclick="playPause1()">
                <li class="fa fa-play"></li>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
            <h5 class="h5-big">HOW TO </h5>
            <a href=".detil.html" class="uppercase bold">recipe</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="thumbnail-img">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <video id="video1">
                    <source src="video/inspiration-1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary play" onclick="playPause()">
                <li class="fa fa-play"></li>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
            <h5 class="h5-big">HOW TO </h5>
            <a href=".detil.html" class="uppercase bold">recipe</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");

function playPause() {
    if (myVideo.paused)
        myVideo.play();
    else
        myVideo.pause();
}

var myVideoa = document.getElementById("video2");

function playPause1() {
    if (myVideoa.paused)
        myVideoa.play();
    else
        myVideoa.pause();
}
```

In this code I have to add the script and as many as class on video I have. Is there any other way to make it so that I don't have to add the script whenever I want to add another video?

I tried to use `document.getElementsByClassName("video")` but it's not working. How can I add as many as videos in 1 page but I don't have to add additional scripts?

Comment: Did you add the class name video to your HTML elements?

Comment: my code right now is working, but if i wanna add a new video i have to create new function and id and script. any idea more efficient?

Comment: i add it sir. but not workin

Comment: You could pass the video id to the function as a variable...

Comment: @ andre3wap nggg,sorry dumb question. how can i do that sir? i dont know anything about jquery honestly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a single event handler to all `button` elements and traverse the DOM to find their related `video` element. As you've tagged the question with jQuery, here's a jQuery implementation:

```
$('.play').click(function() {
    var video = $(this).closest('.thumbnail').find('video')[0];
    if (video.paused)
        video.play();
    else
        video.pause();
});
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary play">
    <li class="fa fa-play"></li>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you already have a solution, but here is my idea :)

Each button would have the `ID` for the video:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary play" id="video1" onclick="playPause()"><li class="fa fa-play"></li></button>

<button class="btn btn-primary play" id="video2" onclick="playPause()"><li class="fa fa-play"></li></button>
```

Then, your Script would look like this:

```
 $("button").click(function(){
    var videoId = $(this).attr("id");
  playPause(videoId);

});


function playPause(videoId){
  var myVideo = document.getElementById(videoId); 

      if (myVideo.paused){
        myVideoa.play(); 
      }else {
        myVideo.pause(); 
      }
 }
```